# Unable to get RecordsWritten in OutputMetrics in Spark Sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am creating a custom spark listener and adding it to running sparkContext but even after doing that I am having an issue when getting **recordsWritten** from **OutputMetrics** if I am performing the DataFrame operation.

when I run below (non DataFrame) :

```
import org.apache.spark.scheduler.{SparkListener, SparkListenerTaskEnd}
    var recordsWrittenCount = 0L
    spark.sparkContext.addSparkListener(new SparkListener() {
      override def onTaskEnd(taskEnd: SparkListenerTaskEnd) {
        synchronized {
          recordsWrittenCount += taskEnd.taskMetrics.outputMetrics.recordsWritten
        }
      }
    })
    spark.sparkContext.parallelize(1 to 10, 2).saveAsTextFile(outputPath)
    println("Records Written: " + recordsWrittenCount)
```

Then I am able to get **recordsWritten**

But When I run below:

```
import org.apache.spark.scheduler.{SparkListener, SparkListenerTaskEnd}
    var recordsWrittenCount = 0L
    spark.sparkContext.addSparkListener(new SparkListener() {
      override def onTaskEnd(taskEnd: SparkListenerTaskEnd) {
        synchronized {
          recordsWrittenCount += taskEnd.taskMetrics.outputMetrics.recordsWritten
        }
      }
    })
    import spark.implicits._
    val someDF = Seq(
      (8, "bat"),
      (64, "mouse"),
      (-27, "horse")
    ).toDF("number", "word")
    someDF.write.save(outputPath)

    println("Records Written: " + recordsWrittenCount)
```

I am getting **0 recordsWritten**

Can anybody, please let me know why it is happening!!

PS: Using *Apache Spark 2.2*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out as it was known bug in Apache Spark 2.2 which was later solved in Apache Spark 2.3

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22605